# RestTemplate for local file testing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Since I want to use the RestTemplate from Spring I want to use the same class as well for Unit-Testing. The idea would be to download a JSON-File and save it locally for the purpose of testing. Therefore I would like to change the URI from a HTTP to a File address. When it as File-address I get an Excpetion

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class [sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection] must be an instance of class java.net.HttpURLConnection`

```
urlGETList = "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=volodiaL";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
CountryInfoResponse results = restTemplate.getForObject(urlGETList, CountryInfoResponse.class);
```

Any ideas how I can use the same classes for Unit-Testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could look into [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/).

Wiremock allows subbing of requests. The advantage is that you really test the complete stack and your tests make real requests against a server responding with mock responses. These mock response bodies can be files (there are other possibilities as well.)

In your unit test you set up wiremock server like this:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(port);
```

Then you can setup a stub with a file response like this:

```
public void givenResponse(int statusCode, MediaType contentType, String bodyPath) {
        String responseBody;
        try (InputStream data = new ClassPathResource(bodyPath).getInputStream()) {
            responseBody = copyToString(data, UTF_8);
        }

        stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo(getWireMockUri().getPath()))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(statusCode)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", contentType.toString())
                        .withHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(responseBody.length()))
                        .withBody(responseBody)
                ));
    }
```

You could also put the complete stub into a stub file like described [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/)

Afterwards you can check if a certain request has been made:

```
verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/form"))
                .withHeader("Content-Type", containing(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)));
```

You can find out more about verification [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/)

You would use the `RestTemplate` to make requests. You just need to have host and port configurable so you can use localhost and the wiremock port in your tests.

Comment: @LeO what was the result of your verification? Did it help?